# Stop Rerendering Child Components When Parent State Changes in React

Tags: reactjs

I have a React component, Activity, with a DataTable and a Drawer (from Material UI). I set whether the Drawer is open based on the `isDrawerOpen` property the Activity component's state. However, when `isDrawerOpen` is updated, Activity, Drawer, and DataTable all rerender.

I don't want `DataTable` to rerender because nothing has changed. I have tried to use `React.memo` and I've tried `useEffect` in conjunction with `useRef` in my DataTable functional component to not rerender if the props are the same. It's not working. How can I prevent this child component from rerendering when none of its props change?

```
const Activity = props => {
   const [isDrawerOpen, setIsDrawerOpen] = useState(false);
   const [tableData, setTableData] = useState(["banana", "orange", "apple"]);

   return (
      <div>
        <DataTable data={tableData} onRowClick={() => setIsDrawerOpen(true) } />
        <Drawer open={isDrawerOpen}>Some Drawer Content </Drawer>
      </div>
   )
}
```

Comment: When a functional component rerenders, it'll rerender its tree. You need to memoize any props sent to children (i.e. useMemo, useCallback).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Something actually is changing though... it's constructing a new function on each render for `onRowClick`, which then forces the child to re-render because it gets new props. This is what the [`useCallback`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback) hook is for:

```js
const Activity = props => {
   const [isDrawerOpen, setIsDrawerOpen] = useState(false);
   const [tableData, setTableData] = useState(["banana", "orange", "apple"]);

   // Because `setIsDrawerOpen` never changes across renders, it's safe to
   // pass an empty deps array as the second argument.
   const onRowClick = useCallback(() => setIsDrawerOpen(true), []);

   return (
      <div>
        <DataTable data={tableData} onRowClick={onRowClick} />
        <Drawer open={isDrawerOpen}>Some Drawer Content </Drawer>
      </div>
   );
}
```

Answer (score -1):

in addition to Ross's answer, you may need to wrap the child component inside useMemo() hook just like below snippet, this will prevent the child to rerender unless until the props change.

```
React.memo(function Child(props) {
 // Do something
})
```